# How does this function print the correct HEX of the given argument

Tags: c, memory

During my time reading CS:APP 3rd Edition, i stumbled up on this piece of code, who knows whilst reading into the book more i might get a proper explanation but until now i do not quite understand how this retrieves the correct Hexadecimal number.

I hope someone here would be able to give me a thorough explanation.

What does casting a pointer to the adress of a piece of memory do?

```
typedef unsigned char *byte_pointer;

void show_bytes(byte_pointer start, size_t len)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        printf(" %.2x", start[i]);
    printf("\n");
    }

void show_int(int x)
{
    show_bytes((byte_pointer) &x, sizeof(int));
}
```

And by how, do i mean how is the integer stored into the memory, because when i print it as a %d with as example 100 as the given int. it will print:

```
100 0 0 0
```

however when i use 1000, it will print:

```
232 3 0 0
```

Comment: Have you looked at the format specifiers for printf?

Comment: @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts While the relevant information may be identical in this case, better do not recommend a c++ reference for c functions. There may be subtle differences.

Comment: 3 x 256 + 232 = 1000

Comment: What the hell is CS:APP 3rd edition? What happened to the previous editions? Has been another one edited since then?  PLEASE, DON'T USE ACHRONYMS.  What if I had commented like this?  WTHICS:A 3d E? WHTTPE? HBAOET? ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&x` gives the pointer where x is memorized, since x is an int, it gives a pointer to an int (4 bytes).

`(byte_pointer) &x` gives instead the pointer to a char (a single byte) so that the for loop can go through every single byte of the int (`start[i]` points to the i-th byte and not to the i-th int).

Answer (score 0):

That prints each array element as a two digit hex number as the format `%.2x` shows.  You can see it also written as `%02x` or `%02X` (using uppercase letters) and preceded by a space.  You can see it printed also as:

```
while (len--) printf(" %02x", start++);
```

in a way more compact (and difficult to understand to newcomers)